# Confusion on kinetic energy quadratic forms and eigenfrequencies

Tags: energy, harmonic-oscillator, conventions, eigenvalue, normal-modes

I am new to the idea of expressing kinetic energy in terms of the quadratic form. I noticed that online, people often express the kinetic energy as:

$$T = \frac{1}{2} \dot q^T M \dot q \tag{1}$$

where $q$ is the coordinates of a system and $M$ is the mass matrix. My textbook however [Ref. 1, eq. (9.1)], expresses the total kinetic energy as:

$$T = \dot q^T A \dot q \tag{2}$$

So if we compare $(1)$ and $(2)$, then we can conclude that

$$A = \frac{1}{2} M I$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix.

When calculating eigenfrequencies, we solve the equation

$$(B-\omega^2A)x = 0$$

where B is the potential energy matrix, given that the total potential energy, $V$ is equal to $q^T B q$

In an example in my textbook, I noticed that by using $(2)$, for an eigenvector $x_i$, I obtain an incorrect eigenfrequency if i substitute A for $\frac{1}{2} MI$. In fact, my answer is 2 times larger than the textbook answer, because the textbook states that the correct answer is obtained by substituting $A$ as $MI$.

Is this a problem to be concerned of? Because clearly the eigenfrequencies differ depending on whether you substitute $A$ as $\frac{1}{2} MI$ or $MI$

References:

1. K.F. Riley et al, *Math methods in Physics;* [Section 9.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9lOC.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Your eigenvalue equation is correct when neither the kinetic nor the potential term includes the factor of $1/2$, or when they both include this factor. It is not correct if only one of these terms has the $1/2$.

By the way, both $M$ and $A$ are matrices so there is no need for $I$.

Comment: So if B has no 1/2 scalar multiple but A has, then A should include the 1/2?

Comment: It should *not*. If the $B$ term doesn’t have the $1/2$ in front, then the $A$ term should not either, if you want to use the eigenvalue equation you wrote.

Comment: hi I had a look at it. do you think there is an error here? https://imgur.com/a/bNlKC5j

Comment: This is the image of the problem https://imgur.com/a/RCqJHBH